# only remove 1 record from duplicated (access database)

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, duplicates, relational-database

im making a reservation system, but i'm stuck at the moment.

Microsoft acces 2010 Tables:

```
-drinks
-ordered_drinks
```

structure

```
tables:
-id,
-..,
-...,

drinks:
-id,
-title,
-price,

ordered_drinks:
-id,
-drink_id,
-table_id,
```

and i want to only remove 1 of the duplicated rows in the ordered drinks table, but if i try to only remove 1 drink from the duplicates it will remove all the drinks with the same drink_id

```
   public bool deleteDrink(int di)
    {
        bool removed= false;
        dbcom = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM ordered_drinks WHERE table_id=@tableId", dbcon);
        dbcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableId",tableId);
        removed = (dbcom.ExecuteNonQuery() >=1)? true : false;
        return removed;//return boolean
    }
```

Does anyone know the sql statement to only remove 1 row from the duplicates?

i think it is somewhere in this direction:

delete * drinks_ordered where drink_id in (select top(1) WHERE drink_id=@drink_id AND table_id=@tableId

Comment: What precisely is duplicated?  The entire row; including id, drink_id and table_id; or just the table_id?

Comment: Looks like your SQL statement is deleting all the ordered_drinks from the table with the table_id equal to the value in the tableId field.
Should be something like DELETE FROM ordered_drinks WHERE table_id=@tableId AND drink_id=@di

Comment: i have tried that to, but the problem will stay the same because i have duplicates in my drink id, i only want to remove 1 drink from all the drinks with the same drink_id.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think the best way to de-dupe tables is grab the row values, delete all the rows, and insert one back in. Since you're using Access that's probably the only way to do it - THEN, put a primary key on that table so you don't have the problem again. With SQL Server, you can "SET ROWCOUNT 1" and then all operations after that will only affect one row, so you can effectively delete one row only, when the where clause points to many rows - problem with that method is if you have triplicates, you'll be left with two rows and have to run the statement again and again until you only have one row left. With the "store values, delete all, re-insert" method, you're guaranteed to have only one row when you're done.

Comment: That ROWCOUNT "solution" is an even worse violation of sound relational principles than the possible appearance of duplicate rows is.

Comment: No you're not doing anything twice in this method. Save the column values, delete all the rows, re-insert. Only have to do that once. With the rowcount=1 method, you have to repeat it for every 'extra' row.

Comment: if have tried this: SET ROWCOUNT 1 delete FROM drink_ordered WHERE drink_id=@drink_id AND table_id=@tableId , but it still isn't working, thankyou for helping

Comment: Access doesn't have that feature. Sorry to be confusing. I only mentioned that method because it's a popular method to remove duplicated in more fully featured databases. You will have to do the "re-inserting" method. Be real careful with that, make a backup first. You will only have to do this once, so doing it by hand is ok - you're going to put a primary key to prevent this from happening again.